# JSON file not getting updated on to the server

Tags: php, json, linux, centos

I am unable to write the JSON file on to the server using below code:

```
<form method="POST">
<a href="index.php">Back</a>
<p>
    <label for="id">ID</label>
    <input type="text" id="id" name="id">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="address">Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="gender">Gender</label>
    <input type="text" id="gender" name="gender">
</p>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    //open the json file
    $data = file_get_contents('members.json');
    $data = json_decode($data);

    //data in out POST
    $input = array(
        'id' => $_POST['id'],
        'firstname' => $_POST['firstname'],
        'lastname' => $_POST['lastname'],
        'address' => $_POST['address'],
        'gender' => $_POST['gender']
    );

    //append the input to our array
    $data[] = $input;
    //encode back to json
    $data = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    file_put_contents('members.json', $data);

    header('location: index.php');
}
?>
```

The code works perfectly in the localhost.
I have set the permission to all the necessary directories.
Linux Server has PHP 5.4.16 version installed.

Kindly let me know any solution for the above issue.

Comment: A good starting point would be to check any relevant error in the php error log

Comment: The way you asked the question, is good. But you didn't mentioned what is the exact problem. Are you getting any error/exception there in server ? What you can see in the logs ? Have you got a chance to debug server code ? Is it reaching the controller .. etc.

Comment: You said you checked file permissions but did you check the "usual suspect"? I mean SeLinux :)

Comment: Did you can check you have data on your json file

Comment: Why are you using the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`?  Seems unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code and commented along the way.  Please run and let me know what your code says.

**Updated**

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){


    //Check to see if file exist.
    echo file_exists('members.json') ? 'Found it' : 'What file';

    //open the json file
    $data = file_get_contents('members.json');

    $data = json_decode($data, TRUE); //<-- This was being outputted as an object.  I added the
    //TRUE flag to output as an array.

    //Lets test for some json errors.
    echo 'Decode json errors: ' . json_last_error();

    //data in out POST
    //Since your $data is an array now, you can add another array to your $data array.
    $input = array(
        'id' => $_POST['id'],
        'firstname' => $_POST['firstname'],
        'lastname' => $_POST['lastname'],
        'address' => $_POST['address'],
        'gender' => $_POST['gender']
    );

    //append the input to our array
    $data[] = $input;
    //encode back to json
    $data = json_encode($data); //Do you really need the json pretty print?  Out it goes.

    //For testing purposes run this line and report back what it says.
    echo 'Encode json errors: ' . json_last_error();

    //It looks like the file is not writable.  So we are going to change the permissions.
    if(!is_writable('members.json')){

      chmod('members.json', 0777); //This pretty much gives full read-write permissions to that file.

    }

    //For giggles lets test to see if you have your permissions set up to write.
    echo is_writable('members.json') ? 'Yup' : 'No way';


    file_put_contents('members.json', $data);

    //We are going to change the permissions back to readonly.
    //You should read up on permissions and how to properly set them.
    chmod('members.json', 0644); //This restricts to read only.

}
```

Comment: I made some changes...  Copy and paste the new code in.  Run it and let me know what it says.

Comment: I have used your code and the displayed output as **Encode json errors: 0 No way** @Joseph_J

Comment: There should have been more output:  Like either "Found it" or "What file" and "Decode json errors"... plus what you have already told me...  What it appears is that you do not have write privileges for that file.  I added code to change that, but it appears that was not successful.  What are the current permissions for that file?

Comment: **Found itDecode json errors: 0Encode json errors: 0Yup** After updating the SElinux I am getting **Yup** for is_writable

Comment: Looks like it should work now.  You should have an updated json file in your directory.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer while searching and is as below I updated
Login as root and run the below commands

```
chcon -t public_content_rw_t /var/www
setsebool -P allow_smbd_anon_write 1
setsebool -P allow_httpd_anon_write 1
```

https://serverfault.com/questions/131105/